# How to ease out the retopology works on Blender, like in Zbrush with groups and remesh, for a character you need to animate?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, zbrush

I've been using Blender to sculpt recently, and I'm sculpting a character that I want to animate.

I'd like to make groups to remesh separately from the rest of the mesh, and ease out the retopology work to then project it on the hi-res mesh, then make a displacement map out of the hi-res mesh to apply on my low res retopology.

A bit like what you can do in zbrush.

Is there a similar way to do that in blender ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer with Blender version 2.83. There's a new feature called *Face Sets*, when remeshing you can tick the box to preserve the face sets in tool layer > Remesh.
But you have to make sure you ticked off "Dyntopo" before, or you won't be able to remesh.

[image: here's the path to make it more clear.]